# leaflet map issue this._events[type].push is not a function

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.markercluster, angular17

this._events[type].push is not a function.
above error come from inbuilt package of leaflet in angular 17
(leaflet-src.js:532:24)

I have try with below link
https://www.ultimateakash.com/blog-details/Ii1DQGAKYAo=/How-To-Integrate-Leaflet-Maps-in-Angular-2022

I have also try with below code:-
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xk5zsq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I have also try below git code.
https://github.com/bluehalo/ngx-leaflet/blob/master/CHANGES.md